# Выполнить действие при нажатии на чекбокс в колонке

Tags: c#

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool)dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value == true) MessageBox.Show("true");
        if ((bool)dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value == false) MessageBox.Show("false");

        MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString());
    }
```

Этот код работает отлично для всех полей, кроме поля с чекбоксами (`DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`).
Мне же нужно выполнить действие при нажатии на чекбокс в колонке.

Comment: На сколько я помню, `CellValueChanged` сработает только после того, как Вы ячейку "покините". Так что если Вам надо "отлавливать" изменение раньше используйте другое событие. Например, указанное в ответе ниже.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю самый простой вариант отлавливать событие `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` для проверки изменения состояния CheckBox-ов.

Больше информации:

[DataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged(VS.80).aspx)